# Insert sibling node into xml document

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, xmldocument

I have a .net web application that uses XmlDocument to load an XML String.  The format of the XML is as follows:

```
<Sections name="Section Opening Page" PageContentID="201" Template="ReportTags">
  <Chapter Name="Introduction" PageContentID="202" Template="ReportTags">
    <Pages Name="Why this Document?" PageContentID="203" Template="ReportTags" />
    <Pages Name="Target Audience" PageContentID="204" Template="ReportTags" />
  </Chapter>
  <Chapter Name="Detailed Results" PageContentID="205" Template="ReportTags">
    <Pages Name="Question List" PageContentID="206" Template="ReportTags" />
    <Pages Name="Answers" PageContentID="207" Template="ReportTags" />
    <Pages Name="Comments" PageContentID="208" Template="ReportTags" />
  </Chapter>
  <Chapter Name="Appendix 1" PageContentID="209" Template="ReportTags">
    <Pages Name="Page 1" PageContentID="210" Template="ReportTags" />
    <Pages Name="Page 2" PageContentID="211" Template="ReportTags" />
    <Pages Name="Page 3" PageContentID="212" Template="ReportTags" />
  </Chapter>
  <Chapter Name="Appendix 2" PageContentID="213" Template="ReportTags">
    <Pages Name="Page 1" PageContentID="214" Template="ReportTags" />
    <Pages Name="Page 2" PageContentID="215" Template="ReportTags" />
  </Chapter>
</Sections>
```

As an example, I am trying to insert a NEW NODE under the 'Chapter' named 'Detailed Results' BETWEEN 'Page' named 'Question List' and 'Answers'.  The code I am using to do this is as follows:

```
try
{
string sPath = "Sections/Chapter/Pages[@PageContentID='" + selectedNode.Value + "']";
XmlNode xmlNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(sPath);

XmlElement xNewChild = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Pages");
xNewChild.SetAttribute("Name", "Another New Page");
xNewChild.SetAttribute("PageContentID", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
xNewChild.SetAttribute("Template", "ReportTags");

xmlDoc.DocumentElement.InsertAfter(xNewChild, xmlNode); 
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

However, it is not working, my new node is not inserted into the proper place, it is inserted at the top.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Looks like `xmlNode` is not the node you intend to insert after - check that you are using the right node

Comment: Actually, that does not appear to be true. If I look at xmlNode, it is definitely the correct node.  I believe my xPath is wrong, but I do not know what it should.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure that `xmlNode` is returning the node you think it is? Step through it with the debugger.

If it is `null`, then the node you insert will get added as a child of the `DocumentElement` as you describe.  If it is returning the Pages node, then you should get an exception '*The reference node is not a child of this node*'.

This is fairly self explanatory.  The code:

```
doc.DocumentElement.InsertAfter(xNewChild, xmlNode);
```

should be:

```
xmlNode.ParentNode.InsertAfter(xNewChild, xmlNode);
```

This said, if possible I'd be using `XDocument`, a part of XLinq.  The API's a lot nicer & more powerful, and is generally higher performance.  An example:

```
var element = x.Descendants("Pages").Single(e => e.Attribute("PageContentID").Value == "206");

var newElement = new XElement("Pages",
                                new XAttribute("Name", "Another New Page"),
                                new XAttribute("PageContentID", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                                new XAttribute("Template", "ReportTags"));

element.AddAfterSelf(newElement);
```

Comment: Yes, worked great.  My bad, I understand your comment, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using Linq-To-Xml

```
XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Load("asd.xml");
        try
        {
            var root = xmlDocument.Root;
            var pages = root.Elements("Chapter").Elements("Pages");
            var mypage = pages.Where(p => p.Attribute("PageContentID").Value == "206").FirstOrDefault();
            XElement xNewChild = new XElement("Pages", new XAttribute("Name", "Another New Page"), new XAttribute("PageContentID", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()), new XAttribute("Template", "ReportTags"));
            mypage.AddAfterSelf(xNewChild);
            xmlDocument.Save("asd.xml");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

It's const value 206 put in the code, modify to your needs

After execution
[image: after]

---

*"That would probably work, but i am not using Linq for this project. LOL, maybe I should be!!!!!"*

So try this, you have to call insertAfter on xmlNode's parent node

```
        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.Load("asd.xml");
        try
        {
            string sPath = "//Pages[@PageContentID=\"206\"]";
            var xmlNode = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode(sPath);

            XmlElement xNewChild = xmlDocument.CreateElement("Pages");
            xNewChild.SetAttribute("Name", "Another New Page");
            xNewChild.SetAttribute("PageContentID", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            xNewChild.SetAttribute("Template", "ReportTags");

            xmlNode.ParentNode.InsertAfter(xNewChild, xmlNode);
            xmlDocument.Save("asd.xml");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

[image: after]

Comment: That would probably work, but i am not using Linq for this project. LOL, maybe I should be!!!!!